# Define Contract DSL to send count of JSON elements from request into response

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have contract defined for the spring cloud contract testing. I am sending JSON in request body and want to return the count of 'keyValues' in the response 'responseMsg'.

I am able to return the 'keyValues' in 'requestedKeys' but unable to get the count. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract


Contract.make {


    name("lockUnlockKeys")

    request {
        method(POST())
        url("/api/v1.0/license/lockunlockkeys")
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        body(
                [
                        "keyValues":
                                [
                                        "0048Q-0MK1N-38V8C-013KP-0NQ00",
                                        "00497-4MK17-38V82-0L28M-11Q24"
                                ],
                        "lockflag": matching(regex("[YN]{1}"))
                ]
        )
        bodyMatchers {
            jsonPath('$.keyValues', byType {
                minOccurrence(1)
            })
        }
    }
    response {
        status(200)
        body(
                [
                        "requestedKeyList": value(fromRequest().body('$.keyValues')),
                        "responseMsg": ?????????
                ]
        )
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions in place of '???????'

Comment: Did you try `fromRequest().body('$.keyValues.length()')`?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you
`fromRequest().body('$.keyValues.length()')`

This worked for me